# Make private changes on Github repo before deploy?

Tags: deployment, github, cloudcontrol

On GitHub sadly, a private repo is for premium users, and i uploaded a repo, but it has lot of login third party, and i want to make those login information private, and i have a MongoHQ connection, and want to make the database private, to deploy it on CloudControl.

How CloudControl and Heroku work, is that by taking the file AFTER the clone on disk or the clone is only 'temporary' file, and they take the one hosted on Github?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to have any credentials in the repository. It's actually highly discouraged to do so. The recommended way is to have your code read the credentials from the environment.

Refer to the Add-on credential section in the documentation for more details: https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Platform%20Documentation#add-on-credentials

Comment: this only works if the database are hosted are cloudcontrol (i use mongoHQ which is independent from their service), and there are other credential like gmail account for sending mails.

Comment: this works with all credentials, since you can add the custom config addon: https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Add-on%20Documentation/Deployment/Custom%20Config

Comment: i dont get the variable (key-value) concept, will i put in the code variables and put them as keys in the commandline?
for example uri="mongodb://$A:$B@kahana.mongohq.com:10067/essog" and the two keys are A and B?

Comment: Simply put the whole connection string as the value. E.g. $ cctrlapp APP_NAME/DEP_NAME config.add MONGOHQ_URI="mongodb://...". Then read it from the environment like any of the Add-on credentials.